# Is any way to change the year faster from a datePicker element in javaFX?

Tags: javafx, datepicker, javafx-8

I'm working with javaFX - in particular the datePicker node and I was just wondering, instead of incrementally changing the date via mouseclick in the datePicker popup menu, is there a faster way of changing the year?

[image]

I was hoping there would be a way to make the year field editable but I was unable to find such a solution.

Comment: Doesn't it have a `TextField` that allows you to manually update the any part of the date?

Comment: @SedJ601 Yes, however, I was hoping there might be a better way to change the year with the mouse rather than with the keyboard...

Comment: not supported, as you already noticed - so you have to implement it yourself: basically, you need a custom DatePickerContent and a custom DatePickerSkin  using that content. Depending on your fx version (is it really fx8?) you need to either go hacky (using internal api, accessing package/private stuff reflectively, fx8 to fx16) or write everything from scratch (it's open source, c&p and modify as needed fx17).

Answer (score -2):

You might just add a second control to set the year more quickly with the mouse and then coordinate the display (model) of both controls.

Comment: This looks like an answer to me. It isn't a great answer because it doesn't have a lot of details. It could especially benefit from some example code. However, I would not suggest deleting it.